# Break URL in figure caption

Tags: captions, line-breaking, urls

I'm trying to break a url that is part of the figure's caption. I used `\burl` but didn't work. What can I do?

This is my main code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, oneside, openright]{book}
\listfiles 

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {imagenes/} }

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage{caption}
\glsenablehyper

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 letterpaper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\include{Chap2}
\end{document}
```

This is my Chap2.tex code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{calderacarbon.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Diagrama de una caldera de carbón pulverizado.}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize,it}, width=\textwidth}
\caption*{Fuente: Valvexport, Inc. \url{http://www.valvexport.com/soluciones-para-alimentacion-y-combustion-de-carbon-pulverizado.html}}
\label{fig:Calderacarbon}
\end{figure}
```

And this is my result:

[image]

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I also used `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` but as I'm using {hyperref} I need to put it in the following way

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
```

But this doesn't work either

Comment: Have you loaded `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`?

Comment: Its not really a duplicate, as the issue was that `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` was not executed early enough.

Comment: @Karalga Thank you, I'm agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` before the url package is loaded *for the first time* - which in your case is by `biblatex`. So if you change your code to:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, oneside, openright]{book}
\listfiles 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {imagenes/} }

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

it works.

[image: Example]

Comment: Hello friend. Please check my edit

Comment: Could you please include a full example, including all your import packages?

Comment: Of course, give me a moment

Comment: Please see my updated answer above.